# Can we use the verb "arrive" with the preposition "to"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I don't think the verb *arrive* can be used with the preposition *to*. I'm certain about it, but of course I had to come here, since I was reading news on *Dailymail* and in the news there was a sentence which seemed wrong to me:

> ...the man continues to lead her through the house reassuring her while
>   reminding her: 'No peeking!'When they **arrive to** the room where the
>   surprise is stored the man behind the camera begins to sing Happy
>   Birthday to Bianca at which point she removes her blindfold."

Comment: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=7476

Comment: I think it's one of those which-side-of-the-pond questions.  I know it's not OK in American English, but it might be in British, Canadian, Australian or Indian English. Have we some natives here from those places who could comment on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your article is an example of incorrect usage. Arrive cannot be used with to.

Justification: *To* is a preposition of movement, and arrive does not show movement. You walk *to*, but do not arrive *to*.

Prepositions that can be used with arrive are at, in, and on.

Answer (score 5):

In the particular use you have given, it is true that "arrive at" is correct.

This does not mean that "arrive to" is always wrong.

> In five minutes, a locksmith will arrive to help you get into your
>   car.

(You have locked yourself out of your car, and called an organization which aids motorists in need of help.)

Note that in this example, "to" is not used as a preposition, but as part of a verb.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  The excerpt you quoted is incorrect.  It would be correct to say,

> When they arrive at the room...

or

> When they get to the room...

but "arrive to" is always wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I have used and heard "Arrive to," but not in the sense of an actual location. "I have arrived to the line of thinking that my colleagues hold," is a slightly-too-formal example of this.

When using "arrive," in other ways it is best to pair it with "at," "in," or "on."